# Maintaining a Thatched Roof

Tags: roofing

Is there anything I can do to prolong the life of my thatched roof?

- Should I attempt to remove moss etc?

Comment: Just curious, where do live? Never seen a thatched roof on a house except in a historical village here in the USA.

Answer (score 3):

It would be worth finding a thatcher - if only so you have someone who will repair/replace the roof when the time comes.

A good one will be able to tell you what maintenance work you need to have done and which tasks you as householder can do.

Answer (score 0):

A lot of traditional roof enthusiasts hang out at http://www.slateroofcentral.com/
You may find a thatcher through a referral request there.